# Delete an specific metadata from an item in DSpace by Rest Api?

Tags: rest, dspace

I am trying to remove a dublin core field ("dc.title.alternative") from a specific item through REST Api. Try using the **DELETE/items/{item id}/metadata** method on a test item by Postman

```
DELETE option http:localhost:8080/rest/items/{mi-item-uuid}/metadata
```

But remove all the item's metadata. Do you have any knowledge on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In *DSpace v6*, there is no support for removing just one metadata entry.

You can use `HttpPut request` to update values, `HttpPost request` to add new metadata entries, but to remove you must remove `HttpDelete request` all metadata entries and then add the ones you want to keep `HttpPost request`.